# Install an App in unpublished theme in shopify store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to install some Apps in my unpublished theme (development theme) without impacting published (live) theme.

I have searched in google but couldn't find any solution. If anybody have done this type of task then please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If the app provides an option for choosing a theme then yes you can, but otherwhise you can't.

Most APPs now install scripts that inject some content. Those scripts are tied directly to the live theme and if there is no option to choose a specific theme you can't change that functionality.

So you don't have a lot of options, if the APPs are not paid you can create a separate dev store where you can do your testing or styling and transfer the theme to the live store once you are done. But if the APPs are paid you will need to communicate with your client that there is a chance that the app may modify some of the current theme functionality and this may be visible on the live site.

The different apps are as follow:

1. Has an option for choosing a theme
2. Modify the theme files directly
3. Includes a script that will inject content and functionality to the front-end
4. Mash up of the above

Have in mind that all of the above indicates that these apps will modify the front-end in some way, there are APPs that extend the back-end and doesn't modify the front-end.